# Python - MemoryError: Unable to allocate for an array with type int64

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to create a numpy matrix:

```
matrix = np.zeros((242993, 9000000, 13), dtype=int)
```

But I am getting MemoryError:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 207. TiB for an array with shape (242993, 9000000, 13) and data type int64
```

**EDIT: I'm running on Linux Mint 64**

**EDIT 2: What I'm trying to do is to create a matrix that I will use save int/float numbers**

**EDIT 3: The question is how can I create the matrix with this size?**

Anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: Multiply 242993 by 9000000 by 13 to find how many elements your array should have. Multiply by the size of one element (say, 8 bytes for int64 type). Divide by 1024 to get memory required in KiB. Divide by 1024 again to get memory required in MiB. Divide by 1024 again to get memory required in TiB. What's your question exactly?

Comment: Yes, it's easy to try to create an array that's too big for memory :)  Next question?

Comment: Is your array sparse? what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Post Updated! @Ehsan I'm creating a array sparse, but I will change most of the values later.

Comment: @TonyStarkus Like my post below, AFAIK you cannot create this size array. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html might help you.

Answer (score 0):

`matrix = np.zeros((242993, 9000000, 13), dtype=int)` requires 242993x9000000x13x32(bit/int) bits which is essentially 9.1e14 bits or in order of hundreds of Tera bytes. Even if you use dtype of bits this still won't fit into your memory. Depending on your application, you might store it differently or break it down to smaller arrays.

Comment: What if I create 3 numpy matrix and them concatenate it in a numpy binary file? Will it work?

Comment: You still need the same amount of memory on your drive. Not to mention 1/3 of that memory in your system which still is pretty huge. You need to figure out another way to solve your problem. Maybe you elaborate on your original problem and we can help figure out another way.